# Excel roadmapping

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have this excel sheet full of features, and for each we got calculated how many days it would cost if one person works on it. Now i would like to map out with some formula when it is expected to be finished.

Though what i don't understand how i can do it, is making an calculation that keeps in mind the other features arround it. For example we have:

- Feature 1 - 22 days
- Feature 2 - 1 day
- Feature 3 - 3 days
- Feature 4 - 10 days

Besides that we know we have 3 developers and only 2 can work simultaineously on a feature. If 2 developers work simultaneously on a feature the time will be reduce by for example 40%

I want the formula to tell me that based on the start date that we set:
for the example let's use today.

- Feature 1 - expected end date 10/12/16 (13.2 days, Which occupies 2 devs, full time)
- Feature 2 - expected end date 09/21/16 (1 day, 1 dev)
- Feature 3 - expected end date 09/26/16 ( 3 days, 1 dev, start date moves to tomorrow as today is fully blocked by feature 1 and 2 already)
- Feature 4 - expected end date 10/07/16 ( 10 days, 1 dev, start date is the end date of feature 3 as until then everbody is blocked)

NOTE: the ordering of the features is critical, and we can expect the top feature to be more important then the one below it.

Now i managed to make a formula with the WORKDAY function, that told me of every individual item when it would be finsihed if it was the first item. But how can i enhance my formula to take in account other item that are being picked up during a week? And the ammount of resources we work with?

I hope somebody can give me push in the right direction! Or can just tell me that this impossible with formula?

Comment: Small push: use Microsoft Projects, this is exactly what that program does. This sounds way too convoluted to use a spreadsheet for, you need a proper scheduling program.

Comment: It's an expensive program iirc (like all Microsoft products) but it does task scheduling, dependencies, resource management and levelling and sounds exactly like what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: `If 2 developers work simultaneously on a feature the time will be reduce by for example 40%` - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mythical_Man-Month :)

Comment: @Mokubai, i have looked through microsoft project, though i don't get convinced that it has the capability of what i'm trying to do.. Automatic planning it has but not for simultaineous features it seems? or did i miss something?

Comment: @spons you can set up people who can do items and as long as those items don't depend on each other then it should (I believe) arrange the tasks such that people don't have downtime. You can also assign multiple people to a task and I'm pretty sure there is a task efficiency modifier. It's been a while since I've used it so I'm very rusty.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Mokubai can you post microsoft project as the solution. I was just trying something with the wrong tool! Thanks for your comments!

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks for the headsup. But i got exactly what i needed. And was not asking for free code writing service. Please let me know what specificly you found unclear to my question than i'll specify it better next time! Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: @spons. Please read my comment again. "If you tell us what you have tried so far (**include the scripts/code you are already using**) ..."

Comment: @spons Done.  Though, as David mentions, if you would prefer to stick with Excel then we can probably still help you with how to bash it into shape but it might be useful to have an example of your sheet data and formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this doesn't solve your **spreadsheet** problem I do believe that Excel is not a good tool for the task you are trying to do.  This sounds way too convoluted to use a spreadsheet for, and instead you need a proper scheduling program.

In the past I've used [Microsoft Projects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Project) (Wikipedia link as it's less likely to change) and this is exactly what that program does.

I believe you can set up people who can do items and as long as those items don't depend on each other then it should arrange the tasks such that people don't have downtime. You can also assign multiple people to a task and I'm pretty sure there is a task efficiency modifier.

It's been a while since I've used it so I'm a bit rusty, it does seem a better tool for your task though as it does task scheduling, dependencies, resource management and levelling and sounds exactly like what you are trying to achieve..